# How to run a shell script in Groovy with arguments

Tags: jenkins, groovy, amazon-s3

I'm in the process of translating Jenkins 2 freestyle jobs to work as pipeline jobs with Groovy, which I have very little experience in. I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the arguments to run inside of Groovy. Here's the important bit of the script;

```
stage ('Clean') {
    try {
        notifyBuild('STARTED')

        dir("cloudformation") {

            def list = sh(script: "ls -1 *.template", returnStdout: true)

            for (i in list) {
                sh "aws s3 cp $i s3://URLHERE —expires 1 —cache-control 1"
            }

        } } catch (e) {
        // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
        currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
        throw e
    } finally {
        // Success or failure, always send notifications
        notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
    } }
```

The relevant bit is `sh "aws s3 cp $i s3://URLHERE —expires 1 —cache-control 1"`. Attempting to run this returns the following error;

```
[cloudformation] Running shell script
+ aws s3 cp e s3://URLHERE —expires 1 —cache-control 1

Unknown options: —expires,1,—cache-control,1
```

Google has produced little in the way of shell scripts with arguments inside of Groovy. Obviously it's trying to deal with each space-delineated chunk as its own bit; how do I stop that behavior?

Edited to add:
I have tried `sh "aws s3 cp $i s3://URLHERE '—expires 1' '—cache-control 1'"` which then returns the same error but with `Unknown options: —expires 1,—cache-control 1` so I get that I can include spaces by quoting appropriately, but that still leaves the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

The cache-control parameter needs **2 dashes** `--cache-control <value>`, as well as the expires parameter.

See the S3 [documentation of cp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

Comment: Tried that, along with a hunch. Ended up with `sh 'aws s3 cp $i s3://URLHERE "--expires 1" "--cache-control 1"'` (swapped quote types as well as the double dash fix, not sure how that got messed up) and I'm now getting `[cloudformation] Running shell script
+ aws s3 cp s3://URLHERE --expires 1 --cache-control 1

Unknown options: --cache-control 1`
So it's recognized expires now, but not cache-control? Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes. Don't use the double quotes around the option group. This makes each quoted string look like one argument to the shell. Also the single quotes around the entire command-line string should be double quotes, so that Groovy variable interpolation will work. Your original command-line with double-dashes on the options should do the trick.